# workflow is not working when use SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges

Tags: workflow

Issue which i facing is follows.

I have attached sp2010 approval workflow to list on item created.

When i insert entry into list manually, and it display workflow status is **In Progress**, it means workflow runs perfectly.

now issue with insert entry programatically.

When i insert entry through code. there is not displaying workflow status in that list item. it means workflow not attached. and not working

My Code for inserting items is

```
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (SPSite spsite = new SPSite(siteurl))
            {
                using (SPWeb spweb = spsite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList splist = spweb.Lists["My List"];
                    SPListItem oItem= splist.AddItem();;

                    oItem["Title"] = txtTitle.Text;
                    oItem["Author"] = objSPUser;
                    oItem["Editor"] = objSPUser;
                    oItem.Update();
                }
            }
        });
```

I need to use SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges function because user has not rights for that list.

User can Insert records through dashboard. 
so i updating Created By and Modified by using System account.

How to resolve ?

or any other alternate way to do this instead SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges

Comment: Something must be happening to the event receiver that gets kicked off for on Item Added. I suspect a racing condition. Anyways, My suggestion would be to manually start the workflow when creating the list item manually.

Comment: afaik you cannot trigger a workflow if you use the System Account, try and impersonate another user

Comment: RunWithElevatedPriveleges should **not** be used to circumvent the SharePoint security model. If you need higher level access you should use user impersonation.

Comment: how to use user impersonation?
any link ?
if i use user impersonation, then can i update Created By and Modified By ?
pls suggest me link for how to use user impersonation.
thanks in advance buddy

Answer (score 1):

Impersonate the user. Like this:

```
   SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
   {
        var userToken = SPContext.Current.Web.AllUsers["domain\\user"].UserToken;

        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteurl, userToken))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList splist = spweb.Lists["My List"];
                SPListItem oItem= splist.AddItem();;

                oItem["Title"] = txtTitle.Text;
                oItem["Author"] = objSPUser;
                oItem["Editor"] = objSPUser;
                oItem.Update();
            }
        }
    });
```